# How do i fix my controller not working in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller, return-value

I'm new to Spring MVC. I want to get the logged in user's info by using session but why does my code return nothing in the view?
There's no error, the other views are fine. So maybe my controller is not working. Can somebody tell me what's wrong about the code?
Here is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "manager/main/{userId}", params = "edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginUser (HttpSession ss, ModelMap model) {   
        
        if (ss.getAttribute("user") != null) {
            User tk = (User) ss.getAttribute("user");
            model.addAttribute("userInfo", tk);
            model.addAttribute("isOpenModalEditUser", true);
        }
        return "manage/manager/main";
    }
```

Here is my jsp

```
<a href="manager/main/${userInfo.getUserId()}?edit" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#modal-lg">${userInfo.getEmployee().getFName()} ${userInfo.getEmployee().getLName()}</a>
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping` is deprecated use `@GetMapping` instead and also remove `method = RequestMethod.GET` inside of it

Comment: @gunescelil `@RequestMapping` is not deprecated. However, [its javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.20/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) says: _"In most cases, at the method level applications will prefer to use one of the HTTP method specific variants `@GetMapping`, [..]"_

Comment: Yes I made a mistake. It is not deprecated. But like you said it would be better to choose specific variants. For example SonarLint shows warning that `@RequestMapping` is a minor level code smell

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code is right, but first you need to make sure that there is 'user' in the session, probably when logging in, the session is not being saved.
when logging in, you need to set the 'user', like:

`ss.setAttribute("user", user);`

after certifying that the backend is correct, then go to the frontend corrections, if necessary.

but according to my tests, the backend is ok, just need to make sure that the 'user' is being saved in the session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have the ss.setAttribute("user", user) but the controller still doesn't work at all. Is there any other reasons that cause this problem?

Comment: Is the controller pointing to the 'main' page?
If you're going to the main page, your request is coming to the controller, so you'll only have to check the 'user' session.
if the page is not going to the 'main', your request is not reaching the controller.
you need to dig deeper into what's going on so we can help.  :)